# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setVisible' of undefined

Tags: sapui5

Im fairly new to SAPUI5 and when I click on button I get the error in the title 
what I did in Is I used the SAP web IDE to create new MVC project .

in the main view JS I put

```
createContent : function(oController) {
    var btn = new sap.m.Button({
            id:"myBtn",
            text : "Content Button"
       });
    return new sap.m.Page({
        title: "TitleT",
        content: [ btn ]
    });
}
```

in the Main controller JS I put the following code

```
onInit: function() {
    var that = this;
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        that.byId("myBtn").setVisible(true);
    }, Math.random() * 10000);
},

onPress: function() {
    this.byId("pressMeButton").setText("I got pressed");
}
```

When I run it I see the button but when I click on it I get the error in the on Init,
what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Since your controller is `this`, and `that` is assigned `this`, you should also reference the controller's view before you can access any of its controls; i.e. `that.getView().byId("myBtn").setVisible(true);`

Comment: I also tried it but its not work...any other idea?

Comment: Did your try with jQuery.proxy?

Comment: @cschuff-nop can you please provide example?

Comment: @shopiaT My bad, having worked with XMLViews a lot, the code I provided works for XMLViews. For Javascript views, use the following code: `sap.ui.getCore().byId("myBtn")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual problem with your code is that you create a static id in your javascript view, but the controller will search the id with a prefix like "__jsview0--myBtn" if you call that.byId("myBtn").

Therefore you either have to use createId("myBtn") in your javascript view for defining the id or sap.ui.getCore().byId("myBtn") in the controller and it will work fine. The first approach is recommended though to avoid name clashes.

PS:
i did not really get the use case, it seems like you want to display the button only after a certain (random) timeframe. But the visible flag by default is already true, so the button will always be visible.

Comment: i love the sentence "i did not really get the use case" -- I think no one does :D love it! :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the standard timeout and byId function from SAPUI5 like this:

```
onInit: function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
       sap.ui.getCore().byId("myBtn").setVisible(true);
    }, Math.random() * 10000);
},
```

Comment: The explanation why this works and not the other one: View.byId() prepends the View's id and "--" in front of the given id and then calls sap.ui.getCore().byId(). This is needed so you can instantiate a view several times and/or have several different views using Controls with the same ids at the same time. The actual id of the control is a combination of the View's id and the id you set.

Basically if you declare a control in the XML-Part of the control, the XMLParser makes sure the id is unique (to the view instance), while you set the "real" id when creating a control instance with "new".